# Navigation Path Issue

Tags: asp.net, web-config, navigation, hosting

I have hosted a web site in to the server.I have a issue with the navigation path.In the application i have used the absolute path as

```
/real/PageName.aspx
```

so in the server root directory must be real.but for some reasons i have given the root directory as

```
www.sitename.com/ProjectTest/real
```

is there any way to add this ProjectTest navigation path to or do i have to change the navigation path in my whole application.I guess web.config can give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

In your case, its better to have it From `Web.Config` in your case.

Comment: As you said Absolute Path to a URL, I'm assuming "real" is a different Web Application. In which case, you can read the Application Path for  "Real" from Web.Config